# Linq to Sql: Where condition order impact

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, where-clause

With a LINQ-TO-SQL linq query - does the SQL generated respect the 'Where conditions' order?

For instance:

```
int[] result = (from r in DB.Accounts 
                where r.AccountID > 10 && r.Name == "Harry").ToArray();
```

If there are thousands of rows, and there is an Index on the Name column, will the SQL query by the Indexed column first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter - SQL Server will handle that.